# break a text file into several blocks with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that contains a diff output, that looks like this:

```
26c26
< Or in the bright light of morning 
---
> Or in the bright light of evning 
34c34,36
< clouds will roll back clear of the summits. 
---
> hello world
> I came here to ask
> some questions 
43,44c45
< How to imagine an orchid boat? 
< It gets harder. But days come and go, 
---
> don't you cry tonigh, 
49,50c50,52
< though only caught that imprisoning moment. 
< A golden leaf in autumn spins into a dark river 
---
> che che che che changes. 
> la la la la la 
> good song
```

i wnat to process this file block by block, where twho blocks are sepreated by a delimeter of the form:

{number}c{number}      for example **48c70**

or

{number},{number}c{number}  for example **90,120c70**

or

{number},{number}c{number},{number}  for example **36,40c88,1020**

or

{number}c{number},{number}  for example **99,100c70**

for example, the file above containes 4 blocks:

block 1:

```
26c26
< Or in the bright light of morning 
---
> Or in the bright light of evning
```

block 2:

```
34c34,36
< clouds will roll back clear of the summits. 
---
> hello world
> I came here to ask
> some questions
```

block 3:

```
43,44c45
< How to imagine an orchid boat? 
< It gets harder. But days come and go, 
---
> don't you cry tonigh,
```

block 4:

```
49,50c50,52
< though only caught that imprisoning moment. 
< A golden leaf in autumn spins into a dark river 
---
> che che che che changes. 
> la la la la la 
> good song
```

how can I do that using Perl?

thank you

Comment: Maybe that helps you a bit: [split a patch](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2561)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string based on

```
(?=^(\d+,)?\d+c\d+(,\d+)?$)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/qJ9cY9/2)

Comment: Simpler and more efficient: `split /^(?=[^<>-])/m`

Comment: as per the delimiter explanation, I prefer to use it because I don't have context about other lines. It can be anything only OP knows about it. As per the information provided.

Comment: He said it was `diff`'s output (which is also obvious if you've ever used the tool).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just dealing with output from [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff), you simply need to look for lines that begin with a digit:

```
my @blocks = split /^(?=\d)/m, do {local $/; <DATA>};

use Data::Dump;
dd @blocks;

__DATA__
26c26
< Or in the bright light of morning 
---
> Or in the bright light of evning 
34c34,36
< clouds will roll back clear of the summits. 
---
> hello world
> I came here to ask
> some questions 
43,44c45
< How to imagine an orchid boat? 
< It gets harder. But days come and go, 
---
> don't you cry tonigh, 
49,50c50,52
< though only caught that imprisoning moment. 
< A golden leaf in autumn spins into a dark river 
---
> che che che che changes. 
> la la la la la 
> good song
```

Outputs:

```
(
  "26c26\n< Or in the bright light of morning \n---\n> Or in the bright light of evning \n",
  "34c34,36\n< clouds will roll back clear of the summits. \n---\n> hello world\n> I came here to ask\n> some questions \n",
  "43,44c45\n< How to imagine an orchid boat? \n< It gets harder. But days come and go, \n---\n> don't you cry tonigh, \n",
  "49,50c50,52\n< though only caught that imprisoning moment. \n< A golden leaf in autumn spins into a dark river \n---\n> che che che che changes. \n> la la la la la \n> good song",
)
```